# Compress image from URL before download?

Tags: java, android, gridview, bitmap

I want to know if it's possible to compress image before the actual download. Let's say image on the specific URL is 500kb big, but I want to compress it to 50kb or 100kb.

I'm asking because I have GridView in android which is populated with ImageViews from specific URL. And if image/s on URL is "big" then download will be very slow. So how to deal with this particual problem, any idea? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this if you write a corresponding service on the server. But it's better to simply offer the images in different sizes or qualities to begin with and then load the files that you need.

For example, have a `foo-highquality.jpg` with low compression (high quality) and a `foo-lowquality.jpg` with high compression (low quality). Your app would load each file depending on its need.

You cannot make any server that you do not control to just "compress" it for you.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. I just wanted to know if this is possible from android client. It seems it's not without downloading image first. So I already have my own web service which gives me URLS to uploaded images from my website. So are you telling me that i need two different kinds of same picture. 1 for thumbnail ( in gridview - lower quality) and second , (bigger) if user taps particular image on gridview, to show full picture ( highquality)?

Comment: Exactly, that's most likely the best solution. At least it's the one I'd use: the compression is only done once, you do not need any special web services/scripts or something.

Comment: Thank you. You've helped alot!

Answer (score 0):

According to me this is not possible,it can only be done after you download the file and compress them. If you don't know how to do this have a look at [This](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29).And if you want to download them in low size than you have to compress it on the `webserver` or your `Ftp Server` that is server side...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need special web-service for it (something like http://makeathumbnail.com/).  May be there are exists something you need, but it is more reliable to have your own resize web service. So your application will download small images from http://yourImgResizeService.com/?imgToResize=URL instead of big images from URL.

I am sure it is the only solution for this problem. I.e. it is impossible to do it only on client side.